# My slideshow only cycles through one picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to design a slideshow using jQuery and I've come up with the code below, however, when I run it, it only cycles through one slide and then ceases to do anything further. How can I get the pictures to cycle through?

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval("rotateImages()", 3000);
});
function rotateImages() {
    var CurrentPhoto = $('#slideshow .current');
    var NextPhoto = CurrentPhoto.next();
    if (NextPhoto.length == 0) {
        NextPhoto = $('#slideshow div:first');
    }  
    CurrentPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    NextPhoto.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).addClass('current')
         .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000,
    function() {
         CurrentPhoto.removeClass('previous');
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
                <div id="slideshow">          
            <div class="current"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="Img" height="382" width="594"> </div>
            <div><img src="image2.jpg" alt="Img" height="382" width="594">             </div>
            <div><img src="image3.jpg" alt="Img" height="382" width="594"></div>
            <div><img src="image4.jpg" alt="Img" height="382" width="594"></div>
            <div><img src="image5.jpg" alt="Img" height="382" width="594"></div>
            </div>
```

...

CSS:

```
#slideshow div {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 362px;
}
#slideshow div.previous {
    z-index: 1;
}
#slideshow div.current {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't think it would cause the problem you're talking about, but your if statement should be checking if NextPhoto.length === 0... or better yet, just if !NextPhoto.length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your script:

1. There is a missing parenthesis (something that you could have easily see in the JavaScript console) to close the `animate` function.
2. `NextPhoto == 0` is incorrect. You want to check if the length of `NextPhoto` is 0 or not, but not `NextPhoto` itself.

Fix those 2 things, and the problems is solved:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval("rotateImages()", 3000);
});
function rotateImages() {
    var CurrentPhoto = $('#slideshow .current');
    var NextPhoto = CurrentPhoto.next();
    if (NextPhoto.length == 0) {
        NextPhoto = $('#slideshow div:first');
    }  
    CurrentPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    NextPhoto.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).addClass('current')
             .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 
                      1000,
                      function() {
                          CurrentPhoto.removeClass('previous');
                      });
}
```

See it on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h7afu5ex/

Answer (score 0):

```
 function rotateImages() {
    var CurrentPhoto = $('#slideshow .current');
    var NextPhoto = CurrentPhoto.next();
    if (NextPhoto.length == 0) {
        NextPhoto = $('#slideshow div:first');
    }  
    CurrentPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
    NextPhoto.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).addClass('current')
         .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000,
    function() {
         CurrentPhoto.removeClass('previous');
    });
};

$(function() {
    setInterval(rotateImages, 3000);
});
```

i have changed few things 
1. function invocation in setinterval
2. moving function declaration above and then refer to that function
3. completed braces at the end of the rotateImages function